# Can not connect to SSIS access denied

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I am facing an issue while connecting to SSIS thru Mangament studio. I'm able to connect to SQL engine, Analysis services but not able to connect to SSIS. I use windows authentication. I tried steps given at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337083(SQL.90).aspx but no help.
On one of the forum I saw that one needs to restart the MSDTC service, Do I need to do that? bcoz my SQL admin said I need to justify it by assuring that it doesn't affect aything else.
Moreover we didn't find way to restart the service, where I can do that?
please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this a question for your DBA? Maybe you don't have permissions to access your SSIS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got other instances of SQL Server?

You may need to specify a server name in MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml

(C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn) or your equivalent local folder.

Comment: No we have only one instance of SQL server. I'll try your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an "Access Denied" error (since you are pointing to an MSDN-article about this) or something else?

Actually I am not sure if the "SQL Server Browser" (sqlbrowser.exe) does have anything to do with it (especially if you have multiple instances). Maybe restarting it would help (although admittedly this is just a guess).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

U need to start the service MsDtsServer100[The service path  - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.exe . The path might change depending on the installation folder].If the service is not started and if u try to login, u get the Access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

It has happened because of administrators' role permission. just run SSMS as administrator and it will be solved. ;)